# Running a blocking socket listner

Tags: java, sockets

I have a socket listener thread in the client side which receives data from the server. Currently I'm just getting the data input stream from socket and reading data from the stream. I want to modify my listener thread in such way that processing of that thread is blocked until data is received in the socket instead of checking my input stream always.

My socket listener thread is given below

```
public void run() {
    listenFlag = true;
    try {
        //instream is a global variable
        inStream = new DataInputStream(clientSocket.getInputStream());
        while (listenFlag) {
            messageType = -1;
            if (readHeader()) {// Check for correct header
                Application.getLogger().log(Level.SEVERE, "<<< passed readHeader() ----");
                if (readType()) {// Check for valid Type
                    Application.getLogger().log(Level.SEVERE, "<<< passed readType ----");
                    readAndProcessMessage();// Read and process the correct message
                    Application.getLogger().log(Level.SEVERE, "<<< passed readAndProcessMessage ----");
                }
            } 
            try {
                Thread.sleep(10);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            }
        }
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        Application.getLogger().log(Level.SEVERE, "Interrupted socket communication - closing socket" + e.getMessage());
    } catch (InterruptedIOException e) {
        Application.getLogger().log(Level.SEVERE, "Interrupted IOException socket communication - closing socket" + e.getMessage());
    } catch (IOException ioe) {
        Application.getLogger().log(Level.SEVERE, "Socket read error : " + ioe.getMessage());
    } catch (Exception e) {
        Application.getLogger().log(Level.SEVERE, "Unknown exception on SocketListenThread:"+ e.getMessage());
    } finally {
        Application.getLogger().log(Level.SEVERE, "SocketListenThread: listenFlag : "+ listenFlag);
        Application.getLogger().log(Level.SEVERE, "Quiting SocketListnerThread Thread");
        DRISMCMStatus.socketListenerStatus = DRISMCMStatus.NOT_ALIVE;
        closeInputStream();

    }
}

//Read header called from above.
private boolean readHeader() throws Exception {
    Application.getLogger().log(Level.INFO, "Reading header..");
    DRISMCMStatus.socketListenerStatus = DRISMCMStatus.WAITING;
    int val = inStream.read();
    DRISMCMStatus.socketListenerStatus = DRISMCMStatus.RUNNING;
    Application.getLogger().log(Level.INFO, "[READ]: " + val);
    if (val == -1) {
        throw new IOException();
    }
    if ( val == SYNCCHAR) {
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

Comment: Blocking IO **does** block until you receive data. Or do I misread the question? _Non-Blocking_ I/O can be done using NIO.

Comment: My requirement is that I want the thread to continue execution only when data is received, if not continue waiting.

Comment: That is what you are already doing. `readHeader` and `readType` use some kind of read-Function, I guess. They are not in the snippet. So when you call a read on a stream it will usually block. That is: wait until there is something to read. Would have to see what I/O functions are called to go more into detail.

Comment: I wonder why in that snippet, you get the InputStream but you do not seem to actually use it.

Comment: Sorry!!! in the snippet instream is a global variable. In readheader() I just take the first byte in stream and check if it is the start byte of my protocol.

Comment: Oh, I see. Would you mind adding the code of `readHeader`? I am sure it will include a blocking call.

Comment: I think Fildor is right, `read():int` is a blocking call to the InputStream already. By the way, you wrap the `InputStream` in a `DataInputStream`, so you may use the method `readByte(): byte` which would already handle the `EOFException` throwing for you.